# WPF .NET 4.0 application does not start when build on TFS with .NET 4.5 installed

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, tfs, msbuild

For a long time I was using VS 2012 and targeted the .net 4.0. The code was build on the TFS 2010 build agent and with success it was working fine on the machines with .net 4.0 installed.
Good thing always comes to the end and I was forced to install .net 4.5 on a TFS 2010 build agent. The result is that my application after being build requires .net 4.5 at runtime.
On Windows XP application just does not start and shows no error.

To debug this I've enabled the fuslog. The only two thing that I've manged to figure-out myself is by comparing previous build with the faulty one (no code changes):

1)

```
System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089.HTM
```

when build without .net 4.5 is calling

```
Calling assembly : System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.
```

while when build with .net 4.5 is calling

```
Calling assembly : PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
```

2) Faulty build generates additional file:

```
The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files\xyz\appName.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = AECA050416\fancyUser
LOG: DisplayName = appName.XmlSerializers, Version=2.2.407.51647, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=306f64099261eabe, processorArchitecture=x86
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files/xyz/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = appName.exe
Calling assembly : System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files\xyz\appName.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: appName.XmlSerializers, Version=2.2.407.51647, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=306f64099261eabe, processorArchitecture=x86
LOG: The same bind was seen before, and was failed with hr = 0x80070002.
ERR: Unrecoverable error occurred during pre-download check (hr = 0x80070002).
```

can you suggest what might be wrong with my build? 
(I am aware that if I uninstall the .net 4.5 it will work again)

Answer (score 0):

I've run into trouble in the past with the *.XmlSerializers.dll not getting re-built/generated/deployed (something along those lines).  It's an assembly that is generated and paired with your application's main assembly/DLL to cut down on serialization performance costs.

See if this works as a simple fix:

1. Open project Properties (select the project from Solution Explorer
   and hit Alt+Enter).
2. Select the "Build" tab, scroll down to
   "Generate serialization assembly" and change that to  Off.
3. Rebuild project.

Comment: it did not help, I' still not able to run the application without .net4.5, thx for hint with GenerateSerializationAssemblies its new for me

Comment: Did you install the same .NET Framework version (4.5) on both machines?  If not, give that a try; you can still install it and just not use it in your project.

Comment: problem is with the one with XP, .net 4.5 is not supported there